# How to use delegated-events, name spaces and attaching multiple event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-bubbling

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZGvx/) jsfiddle

I would like to use this concept of [event delegation](http://ejohn.org/apps/workshop/adv-talk/#19) on each name spaced event. Appernetly it is more optimized than `.big-ul li`.  I unfortunately cannot find the proper syntax to make it work while using namespaces or while trying to attach multiple event handlers simultaneously using a plain object?

```
$(".big-ul").on({
  "click.namespace", "li": function(event){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  },
  "mouseenter.namespace" , "li": function(event){
    $(this).addClass("inside");
  },
  "mouseleave.namespace", "li": function(event){
    $(this).removeClass("inside");
  }
});
```

example of event delegation from jquery's site

```
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function(event){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: +1 for even attempting it like that :) Do you have a JSFiddle for this?

Comment: You have assigned the events to the selectors (i.e. "li") instead of the event type. That just looks wrong compared to the multi-event examples.

Comment: I know the li is wrong .. .wondering how to make it right lol

Comment: Added a JSFiddle with answer so you can play with options, but basically do not overcomplicate your code for the sake of a slight/negligible speed improvement. K.I.S.S. is the way to go.

Comment: I dont see the jsfiddles link... I totally understand the K.I.S.S mentality but learning these things make typically improve my structure and overall understanding of jquery/javascript (seeing that I'm still pretty novice)  I just want to see the limitation.  More of an excerise then a practical use.

Comment: have you tested my example?

Comment: @milkshake it does work ^_^

Comment: is it the answer you want/need? :D

Comment: Worrying about speed on something that only has to respond to human mouse interactions is like worrying about getting old at age 3 :) While knowing how to make things faster is great, when needed, it is far more important to write readable *maintainable* code. The marked answer introduces `command coupling` into the code (considered a bad thing). That is: the code does different things based on parameters provided. Cheers

Comment: I think you should go with something far simpler (and closer to your original code). New answer added. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't attach multiple events to multiple functions like that. What you could do is using an `each` function on an object containing all the needed infos. You could even store your namespace-name (haha) in a separate variable:

<kbd>**[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frontender/hZGvx/10/)**</kbd>

```
var $root = $(".big-ul");
var namespace = 'namespace';
var events = [
    {
        event: "click"+"."+namespace, 
        delegate: "li",
        fn: function(event){
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
        }
    },
    {
        event: "mouseenter"+"."+namespace, 
        delegate: "li",
        fn: function(event){
            $(this).addClass("inside");
        }
    },
    {
        event: "mouseleave"+"."+namespace, 
        delegate: "li",
        fn: function(event){
            $(this).removeClass("inside");
        }
    }
]

for(i=0;i<events.length;i++){
    $root.on(events[i].event, events[i].delegate, events[i].fn);  
}
```

**The advantage compared with the accepted solution:**

1. It's a far more flexible solution as you could send the `events`-Object across modules or dynamically bind events with one single function, when you always use the same `event`-Object structure.
2. You can delegate from one root object to different child nodes, not only one.

**Example**:

```
/* events array*/
var events = [
    {
        root: "root-query-string",
        event: "eventname",
        delegate: "delegate-query-string",
        fn: function
    }
]

/* dynamic batch bind function */
function batchBind(events) {
    for(i=0; i<events.length; i++){
        $(el.root).on(events[i].event, events[i].delegate, events[i].fn);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer seems elegant and I wnat to mark it correct; however could you check and update the jsFiddles because it doesnt seem to be working for me

Comment: Also would does it differ from the top example, being that it's written code less written code lol?

Comment: Hi! I updated my answer with a working fiddle and an explanation why this solution is under some circumstances more useful.

Comment: `$.each` is a lot slower than a standard `for` loop so I would just use one of those instead. [**`jsfiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/hZGvx/13/)

Answer (score 3):

how about something like this?

```
$(".big-ul").on("click.namespace mouseenter.namespace mouseleave.namespace", "li", function(event){
    var eventMatch = event.handleObj.origType + "." + event.handleObj.namespace;

    if(eventMatch == "click.namespace"){
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    }
    if(eventMatch == "mouseenter.namespace"){
        $(this).addClass("inside");
    }
    if(eventMatch == "mouseleave.namespace"){
        $(this).removeClass("inside");
    }
});
```

would that not work?

**EDIT**
you could also replace the mutiple if statements with a switch statement if you preferred... it would probably give better performance too (if you are worried about that).

```
$(".big-ul").on("click.namespace mouseenter.namespace mouseleave.namespace", "li", function(event){

    var eventMatch = event.handleObj.origType + "." + event.handleObj.namespace;

    switch(eventMatch){
        case "click.namespace":
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
        break;
        case "mouseenter.namespace":
            $(this).addClass("inside");
        break;
        case "mouseleave.namespace":
            $(this).removeClass("inside");
        break;
    }
});
```

**EDIT2** updated so jsfiddle will work based on what @Nirazul said.
<kbd>**[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZGvx/12/)**</kbd>

Comment: could you write that out? I'm super nerb

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hZGvx/2/ accually isnt working. might you update this and edit... thanks for all your help

Comment: @MatthewHarwood I cant see where you specified your namespace in that jsfiddle?

Comment: @MatthewHarwood without the namespace this will work: http://jsfiddle.net/hZGvx/4/ but other than that if the event namespaces exist in your code then it should work as per the code provided above, there was a issue with your css in the jsfiddle that caused issues though :D

Comment: @milkshake Can you update your answer? Your code is misleading because event types don't have namespaces attached. This would not work for somebody copying your code as it is.

Answer (score 2):

The `each` answer given will not be more efficient than using the `.big-ul li` selector. My theory being that a basic on() selector runs against the selector once and connects the event immediately whereas the deferred on() with selector runs the selectors each time the events occur (to find the matching elements).

You might as well do it this way and keep it simple:

```
$(".big-ul li").on({
    "click.namespace": function (event) {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    },
        "mouseenter.namespace": function (event) {
        $(this).addClass("inside");
    },
        "mouseleave.namespace": function (event) {
        $(this).removeClass("inside");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AzQBR/1/

*I am happy to be overruled about the speed of deferred on() compared to non-deferred on() calls if someone can run performance stats.*

Comment: is this because of the loop?

Comment: Behind the scenes JQuery will iterate in similar manner to any of these methods (but may do a more optimal job than an external loop). If you don't want to go the the trouble of actually performance-testing each possible option, just keep it simple. If you have a massive list, you may want to performance test, or rework your interface.

Comment: I thought the whole point of event delegation was performance on runtime. Don't you think this would perform better in my example? I'm honestly not sure about this :)

Comment: The above example maps individual events to the items directly using the basic version of `on`. The deferred mappings catch events at a higher level in the DOM and then run the selectors to find the correct element to run the events against. I honestly don't see how that could be faster, but I am happy to be corrected. Performance stats anyone?

Comment: I tried out jsperf to do a test on both codes (sorry for the title, i tried out something else before and couldn't edit the title afterwards):
http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop-object

Comment: @Nirazul: Unfortunately it appears that test only measures the connection time, which happens only once, rather than the runtime overhead (which I would expect would be the issue). Measuring an operation that takes one 10,000th of a second, or one 40,000th of a second has no meaning if it only happens once :)

Comment: Ok, maybe somebody else can come up with a relevant test :)

Comment: @Nirazul: I have changed my mind about the best *pragmatic* solution to the actual coding problem and added another *simpler* answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Having looked over all the answers again (including my original one), I would recommend simply connecting each event separately using the deferred `on()` syntax:

```
var $bigul = $(".big-ul");
$bigul.on("click.namespace", "li", function (event) {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
$bigul.on("mouseenter.namespace", "li", function (event) {
    $(this).addClass("inside");
});
$bigul.on("mouseleave.namespace", "li", function (event) {
    $(this).removeClass("inside");
});
```

All the other solutions over-complicate the code. This is about a straight forward as you can get.

### JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AzQBR/2/

Comment: This is a much more succinct approach, I agree.  The other answers are overly complicated; however, this question was meant to be more of an exercise —more of a, "is it possible" not "is it practical".  Nevertheless, You've actually swayed my opinion on how to tackle this when I ever need all of this. However, I will keep the answer above marked as correct because I believe that his answer fits the original question better.  Thanks so much regardless +1

Comment: When I find the person(s) responsible for down-voting valid answers (*and I will eventually with my reputation scraper*), they will answer for their crimes against SO! :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible guys! But you wrote it in wrong way! Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "lightgray");
    },  
    mouseleave: function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "lightblue");
    }, 
    click: function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    }  
},'p');
```

});